# How to play a song from external storage in Android?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm doing a music player and I want to reproduce a song from external storage but I don't know how to get the position on my method onItemClick

Also I have 3 songs in my raw directory but doesn't appear in my listview

here is my code

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList;

ListView listaCanciones;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer [];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_explorador);

public void doStuff(){
    listaCanciones = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    obtenerMusica();


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_configuracion, arrayList);
    listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });
}

public void obtenerMusica(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

        do {
            String currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
            String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);
            arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentArtist);
        } while (songCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "how to get the position on my method onItemClick?"

The third parameter of onItemClick is the position :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i /*position*/, long l)
```

You are probably better off creating a custom data class, let's say SongData which holds the the title, artist and the **URI**.

```
private class SongData{
    public String artist;
    public String title;
    public String path;
}
```

And you create an `ArrayList` of `SongData` (instead of ArrayList of `String`).

In you `obtenerMusica()` method, populate the ArrayList with info from the cursor:

```
...
do {
    String currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
    String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);
    String path = songCursom.getString(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    SongData songData = new SongData();
    data.artist = currentArtist;
    data.title = currentTitle;
    data.path = "file:///" + path;
    arrayList.add(songData);
} while (songCursor.moveToNext());
```

In your onItemClick, play the music:

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    SongData data = arrayList.get(i);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer. setDataSource(data.path);
    mediaPlayer.start();
 }
```

> Why aren't the 3 songs appearing in the listView?

You don't seem to be calling the `doStuff()` method from `onCreate`.